# How to remove/delete a node & relationship in Neo4j in java?

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, neo4j

I started learning Neo4j. I have a basic idea about it. May be my question looks silly but its important to know much more  from others while learning.
I have small doubt, like once if we create a graph with some nodes and relationships up to a level 5. Then if I have delete or remove any node in the level 3, so how would be the graph with remaining nodes and relationships. Does it affect the graph?

One more is how to remove or delete a particular node in Neo4j?

I have problem in eclipse 3.6 with plugin of Neoclipse(Windows 0.4.1 version). Can any one tell me the procedure of installing and plugin with eclipse 3.6? It would be more helpful for me.

Answer (score 2):

Nodes can be added and removed freely from the graph, and nodes don't have to be connected. So it doesn't matter if changes to your graph create disconnected nodes or sub-graphs. You'll probably want to keep track of them in an index, both for direct look-up and to not lose disconnected nodes since they can't be reached by a traversal.

Deleting a node first requires that all relationships to the node have been deleted.

Neoclipse is a little out of date at the moment, compatible with earlier 1.1.x versions of Neo4j. Some licensing issues have been worked out and that should get some attention soon.